# Sacar total de un bucle

Tags: python, bucles

```
Parada= int(input("paradas")
For i in rango (parada)
    i+=1
     parada1=int(input("cuántos km por esta parada")
```

''' quiero q me diga el total de todas las i'''

Comment: El ejemplo que proporcionas no es verificable. Contiene muchos errores de sintaxis (faltan cerrar paréntesis, `For` está en mayúsculas, la idnentación está mal). También contiene errores de lógica, pues no es necesario que incrementes `i` dentro del for ya que el propio `range` te va dando valores sucesivos. Corrige estos errores y aclara qué total quieres. ¿La suma de todas las paradas? ¿La suma de todas las `i`? ¿El valor final de `i`?

Comment: Como serie entonces?

Comment: Tampoco inicializas la variable `i`.

Comment: Cómo quieres que te responda cuando aún no has formulado bien la pregunta?

Comment: Hola Dudas19. la cantidad de i las define el numero de Parada en tu código. cual seria el objetico del codigo para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Q me diga los km en total

Comment: Crea fuera del bucle otra variable llamada `total` con el valor 0. Dentro del bucle añades (sumas) a esa variable el dato `parada1` que hayas leido. Al salir del bucle la variable `total` tendrá la suma de todos los datos introducidos.

Answer (score 0):

> Intenta esto, ahí con los comentarios traté de descifrar tus
> adivinanzas vato.

```
kilometros = 0
nparadas = int(input('Cuantas paradas fueron? : '))

for i in range (nparadas):
    parada = int(input('cuántos km por esta parada? : '))
    kilometros += parada

print('\nEl total de kilometros es: ',kilometros)
```